# How to get accuracy days completed

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How to get accuracy days completed?

```
- (CGFloat)accuracyDaysCompleted:(NSString *)startDate and:(NSString *)endDate {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
    NSDateComponents *components = [gregorianCalendar components:NSCalendarUnitDay
                                                        fromDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:startDate]
                                                          toDate:[dateFormatter dateFromString:endDate]
                                                         options:0];
    return  (CGFloat)components.day;

}
```

## Example

The work is completed 3 days 12 hours 30Min
Expected result 3.55 Days.

Answer (score 0):

The following example shows the days difference from the given date and today.

This might guide you to convert seconds, minutes, hours to days.

```
-(NSString*)timeDifferenceConversion:(NSString*)dateString
{
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSDate* firstDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
    NSDate * now = [NSDate date];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    NSString *newDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];
    NSDate* secondDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:newDateString];
    NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate];
    NSInteger ti = (NSInteger)timeDifference;
    NSInteger minutes = (ti / 60) % 60;
    NSInteger hours = (ti / 3600);
    NSInteger days = (ti / 86400);
    NSString* temp=@"";

    if(minutes<=2 && hours<1 && days<1)
    {
        temp=@"now";
    }
    else if(minutes>2 && hours<1 && days<1)
    {
       temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld minutes ago", (long)minutes];
    }
    else if(hours<=24 && days<1)
    {
        temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld hours ago", (long)hours];
    }
    else if(days<=1)
    {
        temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld day ago",(long)days];
    }
    else if(days>1)
    {
        temp=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld days ago",(long)days];
    }

    return temp;

}
```

Comment: can we include here month and year for the following conditions?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you calculate the difference in seconds between the two dates, then simply divide the result by the number of seconds in one day :

```
- (CGFloat)accuracyDaysCompleted:(NSString *)startDate and:(NSString *)endDate {
    NSDate *date1 = [NSDate dateWithString: startDate];
    NSDate *date2 = [NSDate dateWithString: endDate];

    NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [date2 timeIntervalSinceDate:date1];
    return secondsBetween / 86400.0f;
}
```

Comment: `84000` is not very accurate 

Comment: I'm waiting for a better solution from you in this case, at least explain why ... I am here to learn too ;-)

Comment: First of all 24 hours are 86400 seconds. But a day can have 23, 24 or 25 hours due to daylight saving time changes.

Comment: Thanks for your replay @vadian